# How to construct square matrices $A$, $B$ with $AB = 0$ and a given determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to build two non-zero square matrices $A$ and $B$ whose product will be zero and who will have any fixed determinant value (e.g. det$(A) = 5$).

I can easily think of two non-zero square matrices that satisfy $AB = 0$, but to get them to have a specific determinant is tripping me up.

Would anyone know of a first step? I imagine it would be easy to start with two triangular matrices.

Comment: If $\det A = 5$, then $A$ is nonsingular. So, $AB=0$ implies $B=0$.

Comment: If $\det A \ne 0$, then $A$ is invertible, so from $AB=O$ we conclude $B=O$.  Then getting any determinant you want for $A$ should be easy.

Comment: If you assume $\det(A)\ne 0$, then $B$ must be $0$.

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ so do you have an example of $A$ $B$ such that neither has determinant 0 but their product does have determinant 0?

Comment: Thanks very much, all. I now see that I was missing some key ideas when I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $A \ne 0$ and $B\ne 0$ are such that $AB=0$, than $A$ and $B$ are not invertible and  this means that $\det A =0$ **and** $\det B=0$.

You can prove this by contraposition. Suppose $A$ is invertible, than

$$
AB=0 \Rightarrow A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}0 \Rightarrow (A^{-1}A)B=0\Rightarrow B=0
$$

and analogously for $B$.